# A faster way to build model in inria Spoon

Tags: java, javaparser, inria-spoon

I am using [inria Spoon](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/) to parse Java projects, and then extract information about classes, Interfaces, fields, and methods and all their references.

I am using the below code to build model of an input project.

```
SpoonAPI spoonAPI = new Launcher();
spoonAPI.addInputResource(projectDirectory);
spoonAPI.buildModel();
CtModel ctModel = spoonAPI.getModel();
```

However, **buildModel()** is very time consuming in **big projects**.

PS: I used [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org/) using the below code and it is more faster than Spoon.

```
Path pathToSource = Paths.get(projectDirectory);
SourceRoot sourceRoot = new SourceRoot(pathToSource);
sourceRoot.tryToParse();
List<CompilationUnit> compilations = sourceRoot.getCompilationUnits();
```

**I was wondering if there is any faster way to create the CtModel in Spoon.**

Comment: Yes, JavaParser is fast to build a model but may not provide the API you need.

Comment: It is correct as I am facing some problems in converting my current application (currently based on spoon) to JavaParser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the full source directory, you can build the model only for the files you need to analyze or transform:

```
spoonAPI.addInputResource("path/Foo.java"); 
spoonAPI.addInputResource("path/Bar.java");
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to parse the whole project.